# Apache Twill HelloWorld application fails - jar not found

Tags: java, hadoop-yarn, apache-twill

Has anyone run into problems running the HelloWorld Twill example? My Application gets accepted but then transitions to the "FAILED" state.

> Yarn application HelloWorldRunnable application_1406337868863_0013 completed with status FAILED

The YARN Web UI shows this as the error:

> Application application_1406337868863_0013 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1406337868863_0013_000002 exited with exitCode: -1000 due to: File file:/twill/HelloWorldRunnable/2ba08d9f-ca23-4363-a7be-426b93c88de2/appMaster.775a1137-6134-46e2-b270-fc466ce7fe91.jar does not exist
>   .Failing this attempt.. Failing the application.

Does YARN expect to find this jar on HDFS at the location above? It seems like the jar gets copied to my local FS at the location specified above but not to HDFS.

Comment: how are you running the hello world application?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have the hadoop conf directory (e.g. /etc/hadoop/conf) in the classpath so that the local file system (file:/twill/...) is used instead of HDFS.